# Jump to current function declaration from middle of function

Tags: vim

Is there a way to jump to the signature of the function my cursor is currently in, then jump back to where I was?

For example, when I have a 1000 line function, where the prefix `x + y:` refers to line numbers, is there a way from me to jump from my cursor location at `x + 555` to the signature at `x + 0` then back to where I was at (`x + 555`):

```
x + 000: void theFn(int arg) {
x + ...:     ...
x + 555:     /// where my cursor starts
x + ...:     ...
x + 999: }
```

And, yes, I couldn't agree with you more that there shouldn't be 1000 line functions.

Also, is there a way to automatically jump to the end of function without being at the opening bracket of the function?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: didn't know there was vi stackexchange, thanks. why create tags, when you can just create a stackexchange for every tag.

Comment: Because you can't create a stackexchange yourself at all.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked and answered many times in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Useful motions in such case are `[[`, `][` and `<C-o>`.

As we can read in help:

```
                            *[[*
[[          [count] sections backward or to the previous '{' in
            the first column.  |exclusive|
            Note that |exclusive-linewise| often applies.
```

```
                            *][*
][          [count] sections forward or to the next '}' in the
            first column.  |exclusive|
            Note that |exclusive-linewise| often applies.
```

```
                            *CTRL-O*
CTRL-O          Go to [count] Older cursor position in jump list
            (not a motion command).
            {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}
```

In short:

- `[[` to got to the beginning
- `<C-o>` to go back to previous place
- `][` to go to end

Those motions will have the desired effect only when braces are in the first column, but from your example seems like this requirement is not met.
In such case at the end of `:h section` we can read:

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings: >
   :map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>
```

---

Unfortunately, Vim doesn't offer better solution as it doesn't parse syntax.
It may change though as Neovim experiments with [Tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/).

---

It also wouldn't be surprising if there was a plugin which provides better support for such motion.
**[Tagbar](https://github.com/preservim/tagbar) could fit this role:**

1. Toggle Tagbar window
2. Switch to it
3. Cursor should be already over the current tag
4. Press enter
5. Toggle window
6. You are at beginning of the function
7. Use `<C-o>` to get back

---

I also once found and had in my config a mapping which could also be useful in such case:

```
nnoremap <Leader>gd ?\v%(%(if|while|for|switch)\_s*)@<!\([^)]*\)\_[^;(){}]*\zs\{
```

Comment: This works well for the languages I commonly use - thanks!